# Error: "500 internal server error" in virtualhost ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, linux, server, virtualhost, ubuntu-16.04

I'm having a problem when I want to use my web page with `virtualhost`.

I have installed **LAMP** in **Ubuntu 16.04** with permissions in the project folder with 777 (*if it does not work well it would not open nor the project, but if it opens*).

My page has a login that when I enter the correct data I get the error: 
`500 internal server error`

Already reinstalled LAMP, changed permission groups, still it doesn't work. I was already seeing the logs that `apache2` throws at me and says this: `Response header name 'Expires' contains invalid characters, aborting request`

It happens something curious, if I enter a wrong user and validate the authentication, I throw the personalized message that I have, however when the user and the credentials are correct it throws me the *firebug* "500 internal server error".

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after login you do some kind of redirect to a "user authenticated" area in which you are sending some meta information to the browser.

Check for some PHP code:

```
header('Expires: XXXX');
```

Maybe you have some typho error, bad formed string or characterset problems.

You could also check for some .htaccess file that set headers using the apache module.